# Como puedo poner botst abajo de input_get en tkinter python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Esta es mi primera vez programando GUI en python y todavia no manejo bien algunos aspectos, estoy tratando de hacer una ventana donde el usuario pueda chatear con una IA. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
python
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

messages = Text(window)
messages.pack()

input_user = StringVar()
botst = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(window, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

def Enter_pressed(event):
  input_get = input_field.get()
  print(input_get)
  if input_get == "dou":
    botst.set("ndea")
    bot_field = Entry(window, text=botst)
    bot_field.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
  messages.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % input_get)
  input_user.set('')
  return "break"
frame = Frame(window)  # , width=300, height=300)
input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
frame.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Cuando ejecuto ese codigo y pongo la palabra "dou", en el mismo cuadrado de escribe la palabra "ndea" que es la respuesta que quiero que la IA dé.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar la respuesta de botst debajo de tu input en el `Text`, no crees un `Entry` en la callback, menos aún cada vez que es llamada. Simplemente vuelve a llamar a `Text.insert`.

Algunos comentarios:

- Considera implementar una `ScrollBar` asociada al `Text`, en caso contrario no podrás ver las nuevas líneas una vez superado el alto del widget.
- Si tu `Text` solo va a mostrar la secuencia de mensajes, considera hacerlo de "solo lectura".
- Usar wildcard (`from modulo import *`) para importar es generalmente un amala práctica en Python, excepto para casos muy concretos en los que queremos solapar a conciencia espacios de nombres.
- Considera usar siempre 4 espacios para identar como se especifica en [PEP 8](http://recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf).
- Las funciones/métodos por convención se nombran en minúscula, se reservan la mayúsculas para las clases.

El código podría quedar algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk



window = tk.Tk()
input_user = tk.StringVar()
botst = tk.StringVar()

text_frame = tk.Frame(window)
text_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
messages = tk.Text(text_frame)
messages.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
messages.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(text_frame, command=messages.yview)
scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
messages['yscrollcommand'] = scroll_bar.set

input_field = tk.Entry(window, text=input_user)
input_field.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

def on_enter(event):
    input_get = input_field.get()
    input_user.set('')
    messages.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    messages.insert(tk.INSERT, f'YO: {input_get}\n')
    messages.config(state=tk.DISABLED)   
    messages.see("end")

    # Obtener respuesta de botst
    if input_get.lower() == "hola":
        botst_response = "¡Hola!"
    else:
        botst_response = "Ni idea..."

    messages.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    messages.insert(tk.INSERT, f'BOTST: {botst_response}\n')
    messages.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    messages.see("end")

    return "break"

input_field.bind("<Return>", on_enter)
window.mainloop()
```